# How to determine UINavigationBar size before device orientation changes

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, device-orientation

I'm writing an app in Objective-C using Xcode 6 and iOS 8. The app needs to be able to be deployed on an iPhone 5, 6, or 6+.

If you want to get straight to answering my question, jump down to the last sentence. If you want to understand why I have the question I do, or maybe how I can alter my UI layout in order to solve my problem another way, read on.

In one of my view controllers, I have a scroll view whose top is constrained to the bottom of the navigation bar, and whose bottom is constrained to the top of a table view. The table view's bottom is constrained to the bottom of the view controller's main view (i.e. to the bottom of the phone).

The scroll view contains subviews that expand/contract when the user taps on them. I want the scroll view to grow as its subviews grow, but obviously I don't want the scroll view to grow off screen because it looks bad and because it would cause unsatisfiable constraints (the table view's top--which is constrained to the bottom of the scroll view--would cross below its bottom--which is constrained to the bottom of the main view...this causes an error). So, I use the following code to make the scroll view resize itself according to its subviews sizes without growing right off the screen:

```
// The max height before the scroll view would go off screen, which would 
// mess up the table view's constraints and cause all sorts of problems
CGFloat maxHeight = self.view.size.height
                  - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                  - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

// The height of all the subviews in the scroll view.
CGFloat height = _scrollContentView.frame.size.height;

if (height > maxHeight) {
    height = maxHeight;
}

self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
```

Now for the fun part. Originally, I called this code to re-evaluate and reset the size of the scroll view whenever I rotated the device from portrait to landscape, or vice versa. However, when I would rotate the phone from portrait to landscape, I was getting constraints errors. I determined that it was because I was calling this code **after** the rotation, when the main view's height was smaller, but the scroll view's height was still large (causing the table view's top to go below the bottom, etc. as I explained before). So, I just moved the code to be called **before** the rotation (I called the code in the `viewWillTransitionWithSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method). This all makes sense so far.

However, now, the problem is that the navigation bar's height changes when the rotation occurs, but the `viewWillTransitionWithSize:...` method does not include any details on this change (it only gives the new size that the main view will be when rotation is completed, not the new size the navigation bar will be as well).

So, I need someway to determine the new size of the navigation bar **before** the device's orientation actually changes (just like I can determine the main view's new size before the device's orientation actually changes using the `viewWillTransitionWithSize:...` method).

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: As per my understanding , you need to fetch UINavigationBar height?

Comment: What do you mean? I am "fetching" the navigation bar height in the above code, but the problem is that that height is not correct for the new orientation until the device actually rotates and updates the navigation bar's frame. I would run into the same problem with the main view, except that Apple provides the main view's post-rotation size in the pre-rotation method viewWillTransformWithSize:.... So, I need something similar for the navigation bar's post-rotation size, before rotation actually occurs.

Comment: Just to clarify: by "pre-rotation" I mean before the device orientation actually finishes changing, and by "post-rotation size" I mean the size the item WILL BE after the device orientation actually finishes changing.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's my work around in its simplest form:

```
/*
 * This method gets called when the device is about to rotate.
 */
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    // Set the scroll view's height to 0 to avoid constraints errors as described
    // in the question.
    self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
}

/*
 * At the point when this method gets called, the device rotation has finished altering
 * the frames of the views in this view controller, but the layout has not finished
 * so nothing has changed on screen.
 */
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    // The max height before the scroll view would go off screen, which would mess up
    // the table view's constraints and cause all sorts of problems
    CGFloat maxHeight = self.view.size.height
                      - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                      - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

    // The height of all the subviews in the scroll view.
    CGFloat height = _scrollContentView.frame.size.height;

    if (height > maxHeight) {
        height = maxHeight;
    }

    // Reset the scroll view's height to the appropriate height.
    self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```